# npm installでUNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: node.js, npm

既存のASP.NET MVC5プロジェクトにAngular2をインストールするため、
http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/ を参考にしていたのですが、npm installで

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.6.26
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
```

と表示されてしまいます。（node_modulesは作成される）

そのまま実行しても、zone.js等が見つからず、エラーが出てしまいます。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

依存関係を解決するにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

手順

1. node.js(v6.10.1 LTS)をインストール
2. TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015(v2.2.2)をインストール
3. 参考にしたサイトの[デモプロジェクト](https://github.com/mithunvp/ng2Mvc5Demo)をダウンロード
4. package.jsonのあるパスでnpm install（ここで上記のWARN）
5. そのまま実行すると画像のエラー

環境
Windows10
Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

クリーンな状態で`npm install`してみましたが、特に問題は確認できませんでした。
依存関係の変化で発生したトラブルだと思われますので、一度次の手順でリセットしてみてください。

1. `node_modules`ディレクトリを削除
2. `npm cache clean`
3. `npm install`

Comment: その手順を実行しましたが、やはりnpm installでUNMET PEER DEPENDENCYが出てしまいます